# Phantomjs not finding script in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, phantomjs

I'm trying to start a phantomjs process from python but for some reason it's not finding my script file:

```
    PHANTOM = 'C:\\Users\\ahald1\\phantomjs'
    SCRIPT = 'C:\\Users\\ahald1\\hello.js'
    params = [PHANTOM, SCRIPT]
    exitcode = subprocess.call(params)
```

Where hello.js contains:

```
    console.log('Hello, world!');
    phantom.exit();
```

This returns `Can't open 'C:\Users\ahald1\hello.js'`

Trying to do this from cmd returns the same error, but `phantomjs --version` does return a value. I'm running python 2.7.3 on Windows 7.

Sorry for the newbie question and thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have saved the file `hello.js` under a different file name, for example `hello.js.txt`. This may happen if you save a file in Notepad or another editor with a file type other than *All Files*. Make sure to [enable file extension display](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/show-or-hide-file-name-extensions).

Alternatively, you may have saved the hello.js file in a different directory than `C:\Users\ahald1\`.

Comment: Ya definitely messed up the file name. Thanks so much for your help, if I could upvote you I would!